# How to hide ExtJS.Toolbar button( inside buttongroup ) programmatically

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have four button inside ExtJs toolbar this button code look like below

```
MyToolbarUi = Ext.extend(Ext.Toolbar, {
    buttonAlign: 'right',
    width: 813,
    height: 32,
    id: 'toolbar',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'buttongroup',
                title: '',
                columns: 2,
                width: 250,
                layout: 'column',
                baseCls: ' ',
                id: 'buttongroup',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: ' B1',
                        width: 50,
                        ref: '../b1',
                        id: 'b1_id'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'B2',
                        width: 50,
                        ref: '../b2',
                        id: 'b2_id'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'B3',
                        width: 50,
                        ref: '../b3',
                        id: 'b3_id'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'B4',
                        width: 50,
                        ref: '../b4',
                        id: 'b4_id'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        MyToolbarUi.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

in above code i have 4 buttons that call b1, b2, b3 and b4 now i try to hidden b4 programmatically bellow codes

1st try : `this.b4.hidden = true;`

2nd try: `var btn= Ext.getCmp('b4_id'); btn.setVisible(false);`

above both way hidden all 4 buttons. how can i hide only B4 button programmatically? and please explain what is wrong with my above hidden two way?

Comment: The first one has no effect when setting it on a instance while the second one should work and it would make no sense that all buttons get invisible. You also had a typo on the first id -> you forgot the closing " ' "

Comment: try with btn= Ext.get('b4_id'); btn.setVisible(false);

Comment: @sra this work fine when remove `buttongroup` but i can't remove `buttongroup`

Comment: AFAIK you could also do this: `Ext.getCmp('buttongroup').b4.hide()`

Comment: This is also the way I recommend because you could then spare the id's one the buttons and it is always the better choice to let ExtJS handle the id property.

Comment: @sra Ext.getCmp('buttongroup').b4.hide() = buttongroup as button group id and b4 as B4 button autoRef but that gave to me error 'TypeError: Ext.getCmp(...).btnSubmit is undefined' in the console

Comment: You will need to check if the ref is setted correctly. Use firebug, chrome devTools or IE devTools to inspect the components. Simply type Ext.getCmp('id') into the console and hit return. To navigate look at the ownerCt for the parent or the items.items array for the child of the current component.

Comment: @sra i checked my ref that is correct i feel bug with ExtJs. this i found via search [link]http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?125055-Buttongroup-doesnt-layout-properly-if-on-a-hidden-card-in-cardlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Ext.get, Once i got the same problem, i resolve by replacing Ext.getCmp with Ext.get

Try

```
 btn= Ext.get('b4_id'); 
 btn.setVisible(false); 

or 

btn.hide();
```

if you like to hide initially, then use config as below.

```
hidden: true
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at the tags? There is no ComponentQuery in ExtJS 3 and using Ext.getCmp in ExtJS4 is not recommend. (As it is in ExtJS3 but there was often no other way)

Comment: Thanks @sra, i did not notice it. so removing those.